# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles Empty

Tags: c#

Can anyone shed light on why GetFile() is empty when I enumerate "**C:\Windows\System32\Tasks**"?

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32\Tasks");
```

**I have checked this:**

- VS is running as Admin
- No exception is thrown
- There are files in root
- I can copy files out (via explorer) to another folder and it works

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Works when I try it... Try running the EXE from as admin from Windows Explorer, see if that makes any difference.

Comment: will this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485449/directoryinfo-getfiles-method-not-returning-any-files

Comment: Do you have permission to this folder? did you access it manually

Comment: maybe you are getting redirected to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Tasks?

Comment: Sounds like your application isn't running as 64-bit. Try changing the bitness or using `c:\Windows\Sysnative\Tasks\` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that you are running the program as x86, and it's [being silently redirected to another folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx) that has no files in it. (It will be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Tasks`)

If you compile it as x64 or AnyCPU, you should see the files.

Comment: Explanation of the background of the redirection e.g. [here](http://serverfault.com/a/315906/54658) and [here](http://icelava.net/forums/thread/5391.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. This was driving me mad. Don't know why I missed the "System32" part

Comment: @ShaunVermaak It's kindof counterintuitive, isn't it? You are running as x86, but you are redirected AWAY from a folder called `System32` to one called `SysWOW64`... wut?

Comment: @Matthew: You pointed me in the right direction. I actually removed the "prefer 32-bit" tick so now it works on both 32bit and 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Just an assumption. 
Do you use any try catch blocks?
This folder can have permission settings which can give you access denied error and void try catch block doesn't show you any error.